# Advantages of adding functions on the "this" instead of on the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I came across a post which says that adding functions on `$scope` is the wrong approach and it should be added to `this` instead .

i.e  -

```
//Don't do this
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  //Really long function body
};

//Do this instead
var _this = this;
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  _this.doStuff();
};
```

[Taken from the 1st section of this post.](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html)

I suppose it is something related to memory duplicate ..

Can you explain why adding functions on `this` is more correct?

Comment: i think it's just your code architecture issue, than js or angular performance

Comment: you may reread the post you link. it's all in there. basically, you should put you code in the controller, not in the view